# Прослушивание и обслуживание одинакового порта в Apache на ОС Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache, сервер, golang, port

У меня есть сервер Apache под Ubuntu. Под портом 1234 работает сайт, который через AJAX связывается с сервером Golang. В main.go есть инструкция `_=http.ListenAndServe("go:1234",nil)`. Мне нужно, чтобы исполняемый файл Го оставался запущеным в терминале, обрабатывая данные с сайта, но он при запущеном Apache просто завершается. Если остановить Apache и запустить Го, он будет в фоне, однако теперь невозможно запустить Apache со следующей ошибкой:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:1234
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:1234
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Я нашёл по этому поводу в официальной документации функцию reuseport и исправил так:

```
Listen 1234 reuseport
```

Ничего не происходит, но и сообщений о синтаксической ошибке нет. Точка с запятой не изменила результат.
Если запустить сайт, затем вырубить Apache и запустить Го, то в терминале будут отображаться успешные запросы, но с сайтом работать становится невозможно. Смена порта на рандомный (8181, например) не дала результата.

Я тестировал **те же самые** файлы сервера на Windows 10, установив OpenServer и соответствующие модули. Всё работает! Но не нашёл каких-то особых отличий в файле конфигурации, пробовал применять мелкие -- это не изменило результата.
Версии: Apache 2.4.46, PHP 5.6.40.
Итак, как прослушивать один и тот же порт?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону port forwarding так как на одном порту и на одном и том же сетевом интерфейсе может быть открыт только один порт.

Comment: порты одинаковые

Comment: Вы не можете запустить два процесса с одинаковым портом на одном хосте. Даже если вам кажется, что на Windows 10 это произошло.